# Set language and timezone in CentOS 7 using Ansible: Can't install locales package

Tags: ansible, centos, locale, centos7

I found the [locale_gen](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/locale_gen_module.html) module to make sure that locales are present on the system and tried it [like described here](https://serverfault.com/a/981742/481076):

```
- name: Install EN locale
  locale_gen:
    name: "de_DE.UTF-8"
    state: present

- name: Install DE locale
  locale_gen:
    name: "en_US.UTF-8"
    state: present
```

This throws an error:

> /etc/locale.gen and /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local are missing. Is the package \"locales\" installed?

So I tried to install it:

```
- name: Install locales package
  become: yes
  yum:
    name: locales
    state: present
```

Both Ansible and manual install using `sudo yum install locales` doesn't work. I also tried enabling the EPEL repo without success.

How can I make sure that the requestes languages are present on the target system?

Comment: Seems more like a bug of Ansible on CentOS than an issue on your installation based on this issue of their repo: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/29200

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε that bug report does not really seem related to OPs problem. [this one](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/44708) looks like a better candidate.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [open bug report](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/44708) since  Aug 27 2018 for centos support. I suggest you vote for it so we get a chance it climbs up the priority list (or submit a PR if you have the required skills and enough time)

Until this is fixed, you can probably apply the [workarround proposed by @wojciech-kopras on april 2019](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/44708#issuecomment-479901767) adapted below from your question (tested successfully against a docker `centos:7` container):

```
- name: Define needed locales (for example, can be set in vars or inventory)
  set_fact:
    system_settings_locales:
      - en_US.UTF-8
      - de_DE.UTF-8

- name: Check existing locales
  shell: "locale -a | grep -i {{ item | regex_replace('-', '') | quote }}"
  register: found_locales
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: false
  loop: "{{ system_settings_locales }}"

- name: Create missing locales
  command: "localedef -i {{ item.item | regex_replace('(.*)\\..*', '\\1') | quote }} -f {{ item.item | regex_replace('.*\\.(.*)', '\\1') | quote }} {{ item.item | quote }}"
  when: item.rc != 0
  loop: "{{ found_locales.results }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, for some added context there's no package named `locales` which is why original task for yum is failing. The package name containing locale data is `glibc-common` (at least on RHEL/CentOS 7, should be the same for 8). However, as noted by the first commenter, there appears to be a bug.